# Why coud not I suggest migration to Physics.SE?

Tags: support

In my opinion [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23733/why-does-reduced-mass-help-when-talking-about-two-body-problems) belongs to Physics.SE, rather than Chemistry.SE. So, I clicked `close` and chose `off-topic because...` option, then I chose `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` item. But after doing so I have *only one choice* to where I can suggest the migration:

[image]

How can I suggest migration to, say, Physics.SE?

Comment: best-practise so far is commenting and flagging for moderators, and/or close > off-topic > other.